# Alternatives to looping through a function taking inputs from several Pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I have been using Pandas for a while but have not came across a need to do this until now. Here's the setup. I have several Pandas series (with their indices exactly identical), say A, B and C, and a complicated function func(). What I am trying to do (in a non-Pandas-efficient way) is iterate through the index of the series applying func().

```
D = pandas.Series(index=A.index) # First create an empty Series
for i in range(len(A)):
    D[i] = func(A[i], B[i], C[i])
```

Is there a Pandas-efficient way of doing the above that takes into account that this is essentially an array-based operation? I looked at pandas.DataFrame.apply but the examples show application of simple functions such as numpy.sqrt() that take only one series argument.

Comment: Could you share the implementation of `func`? Or are you looking to operate with a generic `func`?

Comment: it seems like you want a DataFrame of your series, then you can do func(dataframe), as long as it is properly vectorized, resulting in a Series (or new column) containing your answer.

Comment: I am interested in a more generic function. I can see myself using scipy functions such as the cdf() inside func().

Comment: @jeremycg: So I concatenate the A, B, C into a dataframe and feed it into func?

Comment: Yes, you might want to read up a bit more on vectorization first - see the recent pycon talk here - https://github.com/sversh/pycon2017-optimizing-pandas/blob/master/PyCon%20un-sad%20Pandas.ipynb

Answer (score -1):

If you have only a pd.Series your function should return a series as well.

Therefore,

```
D = func(A, B, C)
```

should yield D as a pd.Series which is a vectorized result over the A, B and C values.

If you want a new column on a DataFrame you could solve it this way:

```
df.loc[:,'new column'] = \
        df.loc[:,'data column'].\
            apply(lambda x: func(x, A[x.name], B[x.name], C[x.name]), axis=1)
```